# ssd(Solid State Drive) vs high processor?

Tags: laptop, memory, ssd, cpu, intel-core-i7

What is preferable?

**SSD**(Solid State Drive) with `enough RAM` or **i7 processor** for a new laptop?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375

Comment: Why not take both? But SSD for sure.

Comment: limited budget buddy!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the SSD. The biggest bottleneck on most PCs today is the HDD. Remember, when the updated Core 2 Duo MacBook Air came out 1.5 years ago, it was well received, despite having a 4-year old processor.

Go for the SSD upgrade. The SSD is much faster, and you won't notice the difference between i5 and i7 anyway.

If you're saying that one comes with an SSD and the other does not, you should absolutely get the version with the SSD. It will be considerably faster in real-world usage.